# react-navigation is working on iOS simulator but facing navigation problem on iOS real device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

react - navigation is working for both iOS and android emulator and android real device but not working for iOS real device

I am using stack navigator, inside stack navigator using drawer navigator and tab navigator, but at the time of running the project is working on iOS and android emulator and android real device but not working on iOS real device

I am using "react-navigation": "^3.9.1"

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator)
const AppSwitchNavigator = createStackNavigator({ // here i am create stack navigator and inside stack navigator used drawer navigator for dashboard 

    welcome: {
        screen: WelcomeScreen,

    },
    dashboard: {
        screen: AppDrawerNavigator1, // here i am using drawer navigator with some navigation options
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#26c281'
                },
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon name="ios-menu" size={30} style={{
                        paddingLeft: 10
                    }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
                ),
            }
        }
    },
    searchproduct: {
        screen: SearchProduct
    },
    postanitem: {
        screen: PostAnItem
    },
    livechat: {
        screen: LiveChat
    },
    marketprice: {
        screen: MarketPrice
    },
    knowledgeresource: {
        screen: KnowledgeResource
    },
    registration: {
        screen: UserRegistration
    },
    postAnItemSubmit: {
        screen: PostAnItemSubmit
    },
    langset: {
        screen: LanguageSetting
    },
    ProductDisplay: {
        screen: ProductDisplay,
    },
},
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#26c281'
            }
        }
    }







const AppDrawerNavigator1 = createDrawerNavigator({
    drawerHome: {
        screen: dashboardStackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home',

            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-home' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    drawerDashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            headerStyle: null,
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-keypad' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    drawerSearchproduct: {
        screen: SearchProduct,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Search Products',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-search' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    drawerPostAnItem: {
        screen: PostAnItem,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'post an item',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-add-circle' size=
                {30} style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },

    drawerMarketPrice: {
        screen: MarketPrice,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Market Price',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-stats' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    drawerKnowledgeResource: {
        screen: KnowledgeResource,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Knowledge Resources',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-book' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    myproducts: {
        screen: MyProducts,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'My Products',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-basket' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },

    languagesetting: {
        screen: LanguageSetting,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Language Setting',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-globe' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },

    drawerlogin: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Login',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name='ios-log-in' size={30}
                style={{ color: tintColor }} />)
        }
    },
    drawerRegistration: {
        screen: UserRegistration,

        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: () => null,
        }
    },

})







const dashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    dashboardTabNavigator: dashboardTabNavigator
},
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {

            return {
                header: null
            }
        }
    })




const dashboardTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({ //using tab navigator inside drawer navigator
    itemsell: {
        screen: ItemListSell,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'item list sell'
        }
    },
    itembuy: {
        screen: ItemListBuy,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'item list buy'
        }
    }
},
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#26c281'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: It was because I used async storage with wrong import, means I imported it from wrong libraries and used inbetween navigation. That was not working on iOS real device, for simulator it was fine.